# How to record historical data in Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I am seeking help with an automation process in Google Sheets. The goal is to automatically record data when a user edits a cell within the range H2:H22. Ideally, the program will copy the cell that was changed and also copy a cell from column I (in the same row) to a new sheet tab, while also adding the date at the time of copy.

So, for example, if user edits H2 - the program will copy H2 and I2 from sheet1, and paste into sheet2. Sheet2 is organized by date, column I, then column H for pasting order. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below will write all changes in range `H2:H22` to a sheet with the name `log`:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 8) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart < 2)     return;
  if (e.range.rowStart > 22)    return;

  var logsheet = e.source.getSheetByName('log');
  var date     = new Date();
  var value_H  = e.range.getCell(1,1).getValue();
  var value_I  = e.range.offset(0,1).getValue();

  logsheet.appendRow([date, value_I, value_H]);
}
```